# Neural network to produce 1 output (FOREX stop loss decision) from 7 inputs

Tags: statistics, neural-network, algorithmic-trading, fann, forex

I have a mix of floating point- and integer values that play part in generating one floating point value. Some correlate and some may not. Using `FANN` I want to see if neural networks are the answer. Given 6 or 7 input numbers that determine a single output number, what networks and layouts to use in `FANN`?

With an expert in FOREX trading's help I developed a system that finds potential entry points (using back testing), these positions have a high percentage of wins when properly played. The problem is choosing the "stop loss" to get this win. The back tester has shown these are winning trades, but the "stop loss" settings are not easy to pick. I am picking based on best outcome. I tried deterministic solutions unsuccessfully.

I would like a neural network make the many data output the correct "stop loss" and the expected results. I cannot account for market events so these losses are expected. Inputs are moving averages, trading range, deltas in closing value, the perfect "stop loss" (by historical results), and some other.

I have a list of inputs and the perfect stop loss and results. I want the black box magic output the "stop loss" and "expected result" as close to perfect as possible. Inputs are double precision values, as well as the outputs. Some are integers but can be presented as double precision. One boolean for trading short or long. If a problem I can train shorts separately from longs.

Some values may not play a part, possibly none, but I want to figure out values for the determination. Sometimes "result" is negative meaning lost money.

Comment: Interesting question, but I think it would help if you explain a bit more about your goal for using neural networks. Merely saying you want to feed the neural network 6-7 input numbers that produce x, a number that may or may not correlate to "blah" doesn't communicate your intent well. I think it would help if you put in a mock-up of the input and the desired output or describe the desired observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a marvellous intro into this domain, you could try [Stuart REID's "10 Misconceptions about Neural Networks"](http://www.turingfinance.com/misconceptions-about-neural-networks/).

### While a highly general question, these would be my points:

- **`fast learning curve`**
   ( having spent countless time with "products" does not get easily justified. Product may quote **speed**, but beware that they speak about saving miliseconds / seconds in production phase on doing predictions on a well-pre-trained ANN, but your time will be mostly allocated on other activities than this -- **first** learning and in-depth understanding the product and it's capabilities and weaknesses, then on ANN-model prototyping and most of all, on ANN-Feature-Engineering, then on design-candidate-ANN hyperparametrisation grid-searches for tuning it's best generalisation and CrossValidation properties )
- **`support and tools for rapid prototyping`**
  ( once going beyond a scholarly elaborated ANN-mimicking-XOR, the very **prototyping phase** is the innovative playground and as such, it is **very costly** both in time and CPU-resources )
- **`support for smart automated feature scaling`**
   ( is inevitable for evolutionary ( genetic et al ) search-processing for robust networks, reduced to a just-enough scale ( to achieve computability within acceptable time-frame ) under given precision targets )
- support for automated **hyperparametric controls** for high-**bias** / **overfit**ting tuning
- support for both fully-meshed orthogonal, gradient-driven and random processing of "***covering***" the (hyper-) parametrisation-space
- support for local **vectorised processing**, means for fast distributed processing ( not a marketing-motivated blabble, but a fair & reasonable architecture ( as [**GPGPU I/O latencies**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065382/3666197) do not help much on trained networks ( finally it's low-computing intensity task and nothing more than a set of single sumproduct decision, so the high GPU IO-bound latency masking does not cover the immense delays and thus GPU "*help*" can even become disastrous [quantitative citations available], compared to plain, well configured, CPU-based ANN-computing )

---

### AI/ML NN-Feature Engineering! <sup>...forget about `6:?[:?[:?]]:1` architectures</sup>

This is **The Key.**

**Whatever** AI/ML-Predictor you choose,
be it an ANN or SVM or even an ensemble-based "weak"-learner, **the major issue** is **not** the engine, but **the driver -- the predictive powers of the set of Features**.

Do not forget, what complexity the FOREX multi-instrument Marketplace exhibits in real-time. Definitely many orders of magnitude more complex than 6:1. **And you aspire to create a `Predictor` being capable to predict what happens.**
[image]

### How to make it within a reasonable computability cost?

```
smart tools exist:

        feature_selection.RFECV(    estimator,                #  loc_PREDICTOR
                                    step             = 1,     # remove 1 FEATURE at a time
                                    cv               = None,  # perform 3-FOLD CrossValidation  <-opt. sklearn.cross_validation
                                    scoring          = None,  #                                 <-opt. aScoreFUN with call-signature aScoreFUN( estimator, X, y )
                                    estimator_params = None,  # {}-params for sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV()
                                    verbose          = 0
                                    )
# Feature ranking with recursive feature elimination
# and cross-validated selection of the best number of features.
```

---

```
 |>>> aFeatureImportancesMAP_v4( loc_PREDICTOR, X_mmap )              
  0.  0.3380673 _ _ _____________________f_O.............RICE_: [216]
  1.  0.0147430 _ _ __________________________________f_A...._: [251]
  2.  0.0114801 _ _ ___________________f_............ul_5:3_8_: [252]
  3.  0.0114482 _ _ ______________________________H......GE_1_: [140]
  4.  0.0099676 _ _ ______________________________f_V....m7_4_: [197]
  5.  0.0083556 _ _ ______________________________f.......7_3_: [198]
  6.  0.0081931 _ _ ________________________f_C...........n_0_: [215]
  7.  0.0077556 _ _ ______________________f_Tr..........sm5_4_: [113]
  8.  0.0073360 _ _ _____________________________f_R.......an_: [217]
  9.  0.0072734 _ _ ______________________f_T............m5_3_: [114]
 10.  0.0069267 _ _ ______________________d_M.............0_4_: [ 12]
 11.  0.0068423 _ _ ______________________________f_......._1_: [200]
 12.  0.0058133 _ _ ______________________________f_......._4_: [201]
 13.  0.0054673 _ _ ______________________________f_......._2_: [199]
 14.  0.0054481 _ _ ______________________f_................2_: [115]
 15.  0.0053673 _ _ _____________________f_.................4_: [129]
 16.  0.0050523 _ _ ______________________f_................1_: [116]
 17.  0.0048710 _ _ ________________________f_..............1_: [108]
 18.  0.0048606 _ _ _____________________f_.................3_: [130]
 19.  0.0048357 _ _ ________________________________d_......1_: [211]
 20.  0.0048018 _ _ _________________________pc.............1_: [ 86]
 21.  0.0047817 _ _ ________________________________d.......3_: [212]
 22.  0.0045846 _ _ ___________________f_K..................8_: [260]
 23.  0.0045753 _ _ _____________________f_.................2_: [131]

 1st.[292]-elements account for 100% Importance Score ________________
 1st. [50]-elements account for  60%
 1st. [40]-elements account for  56%
 1st. [30]-elements account for  53% . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
 1st. [20]-elements account for  48% 
 1st. [10]-elements account for  43%
```

### Precision?

Assembler guys and C gurus will object on first sight, however let me state, that a numerical (im)-precision **does not make an issue** in FX/ANN solutions.

Dimensionality **curse does...** `O(2)` & `O(3)` class problems are not seldom.

Doable with both smart/efficient <sub>( read fast ... )</sub> representation, even for nanosecond resolution time-stamped HFT data-stream I/O hoses.

Sometimes, there is even a need to reduce a numerical "precision" of inputs ( sub-sampling and blurring ) to avoid adverse effects of ( unreasonably computationally expensive ) high dimensionality and also to avoid a tendency to overfitting, to benefit from better generalisation abilities of the well adjusted AI/ML-Predictor.

```
        (im)PRECISION JUST-RIGHT FOR UNCERTAINTY LEVELs MET ON .predict()-s
     ___:__:___________MANTISSA|
     |  v  |                  v|_____________________________________________________________________________________
    0.001  |               1023|    np.float16      Half   precision float: 10 bits mantissa + sign bit|  5 bits exp|
    1.02?  |                                                                                
           v            123456:|_____________________________________________________________________________________
E00 0.000001            8388607|    np.float32      Single precision float: 23 bits mantissa + sign bit|  8 bits exp|
+00 12345.6? DAX              ^                                                             
+05 1.23456? DAX                                                                            
               123456789012345:|_____________________________________________________________________________________
               4503599627370495|    np.float64      Double precision float: 52 bits mantissa + sign bit| 11 bits exp|
                              ^|
```

Anyway, a charming FX project, let me know if onboarding:

[image: dMM()]

---

To receive another, un-biased view about the top-down similar situation to your one, reported from another person, one [might want to read and think a bit about this experience](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32679255/3666197) and just count the weeks and months estimates for making there presented list mastered top-down and complete to make one's final decision.

Comment: Forgive me, but this sounds like gibberish to me.   I was more interested in some ideas I could look up and then run some tests via FANN.

Comment: After a few decades in FX quantitative methods using ANN/RNN/SVM/RF models with pipelined grid-based optimisation and CV metrics for quality of Feature Engineering, I guess to have some bases for statements above. **Once the AI/ML artillery goes this distance, with models' optimisation tuning span well beyond hundreds of CPU-core-hours, I guess I can share a few notes on what may save your efforts a few months/years by excluding things, that do not lead to result**. Clicking GUI toys is sure also a possible step, however an ANN with 6in-1out is simply a no-go model for a serious FX-predictor.